# Symfony - ChoiceType float value

Tags: forms, symfony

I run on Symfony 3.1.6, and I got something strange with a form render.

Here my form:

```
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('foo', ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices'     => [
                '00 h 30' => 0.5,
                '01 h 00' => 1.0,
            ],
        ])
        ->add('bar', ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices'     => [
                '00 h 30' => 0.5,
                '01 h 00' => 1.0,
                '01 h 30' => 1.5,
            ],
        ])
        ->add('baz', ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices'     => [
                '00 h 30' => 0.5,
                '01 h 00' => 1.0,
                '02 h 00' => 2.0,
            ],
        ])
        ->getForm();
```

And a basic render:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.foo) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.bar) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.baz) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

I got this:

```
<form>
    <select id="form_foo" name="form[foo]">
        <option value="0.5">00 h 30</option>
        <option value="1">01 h 00</option>
    </select>
    <select id="form_bar" name="form[bar]">
        <option value="0">00 h 30</option>
        <option value="1">01 h 00</option>
        <option value="2">01 h 30</option>
    </select>
    <select id="form_baz" name="form[baz]">
        <option value="0.5">00 h 30</option>
        <option value="1">01 h 00</option>
        <option value="2">02 h 00</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Why my `bar` render doesn't display the good values? In fact, each time I use a value > 1 and not round to a int value, the values are just int increment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happen because the keys of an `array` must be an `integer` or `string` only ([PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)). If a float key is provided, it's casted to integer [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/ChoiceList/ArrayChoiceList.php#L237) automatically by PHP. Let's look at an example:

```
$cache[$choice] = true;

// when $choice = 0.5: $cache = [0 => true]
// when $choice = 1.0: $cache = [0 => true, 1 => true]
```

Then, when `$choice = 1.5` [this line](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/ChoiceList/ArrayChoiceList.php#L233) (`isset($cache[1.5])`) returns `true` because really checks `isset($cache[1])` and this key already exists, so [`castableToString()`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/ChoiceList/ArrayChoiceList.php#L222) returns `false` (detected as duplicate) and the choices values are generated incrementing integers as values.

I think it's a bug.

For now, use `choice_value` option to fix that:

```
'choice_value' => function ($value) {
    return $value;
}
```

I left a comment on this old issue in Github: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/13817#issuecomment-257297132

Already fixed in https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/20378

Comment: Thanks for the explaination!

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised it generated:

```
<option value="0">00 h 30</option>
```

and then

```
<option value="0.5">00 h 30</option>
```

for the same choice key and value ([maybe because of this?](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/ChoiceList/ArrayChoiceList.php#L222)).

The class responsible for generating the list of choices is [`Symfony/Component/Form/ChoiceList/ArrayChoiceList`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/ChoiceList/ArrayChoiceList.php#L65) so I'd address my suspition there.

However, I don't know what is causing this issue I'd recommend you to look at [`choice_value` option](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-value) of the `ChoiceType` field because this decides how is each choice transformed into a value and if it's not specified it uses just incremented idicies. So maybe try using this option and just convert float to strings.

See: [ArrayChoiceList.php#L83](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/ChoiceList/ArrayChoiceList.php#L83)

Comment: Thanks for the explaination!